# oracle nested table select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, user-defined-types

How can I write a query that lists the first and last names of all drivers, along with the vehicle identification number of the car they drive?  This is what I have so far:

```
Create type DRIVER_TY as object (first_name VARCHAR2(20), last_name VARCHAR2(20), date_of_birth VARCHAR2(20));
Create type OWNER_TY as object (first_name VARCHAR2(20), last_name VARCHAR2(20), date_purchased VARCHAR2(25));
Create type OWNERS_NT is table of OWNER_TY;
Create table AUTOMOBILE (vehicle_identification_number NUMBER(25) PRIMARY KEY,
driver DRIVERS_VA,owner OWNERS_NT) NESTED TABLE owner STORE AS owner_infor;
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define this table, or to retrieve data from it? It looks to me like your statements won't execute properly, is that right?

Comment: No, in fact, my statements are working, and i did not put anything on there, but most of them. I just do not how to select those things from the table that has nested table, and varying....

Comment: A car has many owners?  What an interesting data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't quite match with your question, so I created this variant table:

```
Create table AUTOMOBILE (
   vehicle_identification_number NUMBER(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    drivers DRIVERS_VA,
    owners OWNERS_NT) 
    NESTED TABLE owners STORE AS owner_infor,
    NESTED TABLE drivers STORE AS driver_infor;
```

I populated it with some test data:

```
insert into automobile
values ( 23
        , DRIVERS_VA(DRIVER_TY('FOX', 'IN SOCKS', date '1947-08-11')
                      , DRIVER_TY('MR', 'KNOX', date '1941-02-01')
                      )
       , OWNERS_NT(OWNER_TY('THE', 'LORAX', date '1969-01-01')
                      )
   );
insert into automobile 
values ( 42
            , DRIVERS_VA(DRIVER_TY('SAM', 'I AM', date '1988-08-11')
                          , DRIVER_TY('DAISY-HEAD', 'MAYZIE', date '1983-02-01')
                          )
           , OWNERS_NT(OWNER_TY('THE', 'LORAX', date '1969-01-01')
                          )
       );
```

Here is the query you want:

```
SQL> select a.vehicle_identification_number as vin
  2         , drv.first_name
  3         , drv.last_name
  4  from automobile a
  5       , table(a.drivers) drv
  6  /

       VIN FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        23 FOX                  IN SOCKS
        23 MR                   KNOX
        42 SAM                  I AM
        42 DAISY-HEAD           MAYZIE

SQL>
```

The TABLE() function converts a nested table into a queryable object; it's pretty cool.  Note that aliases are optional but advisable (as always).